# SQL Server 2008 Combine\Merge rows where end time of one row is start time of another

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I can't get this to work despite this helper which is very similar.

[Combine rows when the end time of one is the start time of another (Oracle)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7420618/combine-rows-when-the-end-time-of-one-is-the-start-time-of-another-oracle?lq=1)

Example data

```
groupId startTime               endTime
-------------------------------------------------------
1022    2015-09-14 06:30:00.000 2015-09-14 13:45:00.000
1022    2015-09-14 11:20:00.000 2015-09-14 11:50:00.000
1477    2015-09-14 09:46:00.000 2015-09-14 16:13:00.000
1477    2015-09-14 13:40:00.000 2015-09-14 14:10:00.000
2037    2015-09-14 09:43:00.000 2015-09-14 12:00:00.000
2037    2015-09-14 12:00:00.000 2015-09-14 19:02:00.000
2037    2015-09-14 14:00:00.000 2015-09-14 14:30:00.000
```

The output I want.

```
groupId startTime               endTime
-------------------------------------------------------
1022    2015-09-14 06:30:00.000 2015-09-14 13:45:00.000
1022    2015-09-14 11:20:00.000 2015-09-14 11:50:00.000
1477    2015-09-14 09:46:00.000 2015-09-14 16:13:00.000
1477    2015-09-14 13:40:00.000 2015-09-14 14:10:00.000
2037    2015-09-14 09:43:00.000 2015-09-14 19:02:00.000
2037    2015-09-14 14:00:00.000 2015-09-14 14:30:00.000
```

And the example sql.

```
CREATE TABLE data 
(
    groupId int not null,
    startTime datetime not null,
    endTime datetime not null
)

INSERT INTO Data (groupId, startTime, endTime) 
VALUES (1022, '2015-09-14 06:30:00.000', '2015-09-14 13:45:00.000')

INSERT INTO Data (groupId, startTime, endTime) 
VALUES (1022, '2015-09-14 11:20:00.000', '2015-09-14 11:50:00.000')

INSERT INTO Data (groupId, startTime, endTime) 
VALUES (1477, '2015-09-14 09:46:00.000', '2015-09-14 16:13:00.000')

INSERT INTO Data (groupId, startTime, endTime) 
VALUES (1477, '2015-09-14 13:40:00.000', '2015-09-14 14:10:00.000')

INSERT INTO Data (groupId, startTime, endTime) 
VALUES (2037, '2015-09-14 09:43:00.000',    '2015-09-14 12:00:00.000')

INSERT INTO Data (groupId, startTime, endTime) 
VALUES (2037, '2015-09-14 12:00:00.000', '2015-09-14 19:02:00.000')

INSERT INTO Data (groupId, startTime, endTime) 
VALUES (2037, '2015-09-14 14:00:00.000', '2015-09-14 14:30:00.000')
```

Thank you.

Comment: Do you ever get the case there there is more then one row that continue an existing row?  another row with this data  2037  2015-09-14 12:00   2015-09-14 20:00

Comment: Not yet.  But if I did, I'd want the output to be 2037    2015-09-14 09:43:00.000 2015-09-14 20:00:00.000 where the endTime is updated to 2015-09-14 20:00:00.000.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a better way but when in doubt CTE....

```
WITH CTES as 
(select * from #data)

select c.groupid,c.starttime,ISNULL(d.endtime,c.endtime)
FROM CTES c
left join CTES d
on c.starttime = d.endtime
and c.groupid = d.groupid
where c.starttime != ISNULL(d.endtime,c.endtime)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Holmes but it doesn't quite get the desired output.