# How to concatenate text in one column while merging rows with same start time and end time?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a SQL table like this showing queries users have run and the start time and end times of the queries.

```
+-----------------+----------+------------+----------+
| QUERY_TEXT      | USER_NAME| START_TIME | END_TIME |
+-----------------+----------+------------+----------+
| SELECT * FROM ..| analyst  | 03:02:22   | 03:05:35 |
| USE ..          | engineer | 03:03:22   | 03:03:24 |
| SELECT NAME ..  | engineer | 03:03:24   | 03:04:28 |
| UPDATE ..       | analyst  | 03:05:35   | 03:06:39 |
| SHOW ..         | admin    | 03:07:01   | 03:07:05 |
| INSERT ..       | analyst  | 03:06:39   | 03:08:22 |
| COMMIT;         | analyst  | 03:08:22   | 03:10:01 |
| DESCRIBE ..     | analyst  | 03:13:44   | 03:13:46 |
+-----------------+----------+------------+----------+
```

I want to combine the queries that are time consecutive to get the full scripts run by users. 
The end result should look like this

```
+------------------+----------+------------+----------+
| QUERY_TEXT       | USER_NAME| START_TIME | END_TIME |
+------------------+----------+------------+----------+
| SELECT .. COMMIT;| analyst  | 03:02:22   | 03:10:01 |
| USE ..           | engineer | 03:03:22   | 03:04:28 |
| SHOW ..          | admin    | 03:07:01   | 03:07:05 |
| DESCRIBE ..      | analyst  | 03:13:44   | 03:13:46 |
+------------------+----------+------------+----------+
```

I have found answers [combining time consecutive states](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7420618/combine-rows-when-the-end-time-of-one-is-the-start-time-of-another-oracle) but not one which will concatenate the values of a column as well

Comment: Tag our question with the database you are using.  And, unless users only one run query, you should show data where a user has multiple scripts that you want on separate rows.

Comment: Just use LISTAGG or STRING_AGG or whatever function does this in on your platform instead of MIN or MAX that is how you concatinate across groups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is **island and gap** problem and you will need to use `analytical` function as following:

```
Select listagg(query_text,';') within group (order by start_time) as query_text, 
       username, 
       min(start_time) as start_time, 
       max(end_time) as end_time
  From
  (Select t.*,
          Row_number() over (partition by username order by start_time) 
           - sum(case when start_time < prev_end_time or prev_end_time is null then 1 end) over (partition by username order by start_time) as grp
     From (select t.*, 
                  Lag(end_time) over (partition by username order by start_time) as prev_end_time
             From your_table t
          ) t
   )
Group by username, grp
Order by start_time;
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. In my actual data there were milliseconds of difference between start_time and prev_end_time so I just made one small edit by changing the "case when" condition to "case when ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MILLISECOND, start_time, prev_end_time)) < 350 or prev_end_time is null then 1 end".

Answer (score 0):

Use the STRING_AGG() function. It takes 2 args- column name and delimiter.

Example using your columns:

select string_agg(query_text, ',') query_text, username, min(start_time), max(end_time)

...

group by user_name

Comment: Hi Bar welcome to stack overflow.  For a question like this a good answer would include the actual SQL that is needed to concatinate the columns requested.  This is much more like my comment (where I suggest using the function.)